# Celery + Redis - .get() hangs indefinitely after running smoothly for ~70 hours

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, eventlet

Everything runs fine for multiple days, but then I get an indefinite hang on .get(). The time it takes for the indefinite hang to occur varies, but it's between 24 and 72 hours of running.

My suspicion is that this has something to do with the Redis broker. The output of `CLIENT LIST` in `redis-cli` shows a large number of connections with a very high idle number (see below). But I don't know if this is an issue or why this would cause Celery's .get() to hang indefinitely.

I have confirmed that this is not caused by a long running task. I have also run `strace` and `lsof` on one of the worker processes, but I wasn't able to glean anything useful from the output: [strace output](https://github.com/celery/celery/files/1761489/straceOfWorker.txt), [lsof output](https://github.com/celery/celery/files/1761492/lsofOfWorker.txt).

I ran `CLIENT LIST` in the `redis-cli` on the master server (I have 1 master server, and 6 worker servers) soon after I was notified that .get() had hung. I've attached a portion of the output (the [full output is 659 lines long](https://github.com/celery/celery/files/1761491/clientListWhileNothingActive.txt)). It looks like there are many with a high idle time and it looks like it's listing connections from IPs that I either don't recognize or I may have used in the past (weeks ago) as worker servers. IPs I'm using currently have been replaced with [workerIPx].

Is something going wrong with Redis that's causing this .get() to hang indefinitely?

```
addr=67.205.178.82:43310 fd=111 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.82:43311 fd=112 idle=1060095 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.82:43312 fd=113 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.82:43313 fd=114 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.82:43314 fd=115 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=192.241.144.208:43997 fd=119 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=192.241.144.208:43998 fd=120 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=192.241.144.208:43999 fd=121 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=192.241.144.208:44000 fd=122 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=192.241.144.208:44002 fd=23 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=192.241.144.208:44003 fd=24 idle=1060097 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=192.241.144.208:44004 fd=25 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=192.241.144.208:44005 fd=26 idle=1061197 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=192.241.144.208:44006 fd=51 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.82:43317 fd=132 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.82:43318 fd=133 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=192.241.144.208:44009 fd=139 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=192.241.144.208:44010 fd=140 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=192.241.144.208:44011 fd=141 idle=1060097 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.68:34569 fd=148 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.68:34570 fd=149 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.68:34571 fd=150 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.68:34572 fd=151 idle=1060226 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.68:34574 fd=153 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.68:34575 fd=154 idle=1060100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.68:34576 fd=155 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.68:34577 fd=156 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.68:34578 fd=157 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=192.241.144.208:44013 fd=160 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=192.241.144.208:44015 fd=162 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50152 fd=163 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.188.236:50153 fd=164 idle=1060095 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.188.236:50154 fd=165 idle=1060226 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.188.236:50155 fd=167 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.188.236:50156 fd=168 idle=1060226 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.82:43320 fd=169 idle=1061196 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.82:43321 fd=170 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.82:43322 fd=171 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.82:43323 fd=172 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.68:34580 fd=178 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.68:34581 fd=179 idle=1060100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.68:34583 fd=181 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.17:50302 fd=183 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.17:50303 fd=184 idle=1060096 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.17:50304 fd=185 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.17:50305 fd=186 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.17:50306 fd=187 idle=1060236 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.68:34586 fd=201 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.68:34587 fd=202 idle=1061195 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50159 fd=205 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50160 fd=206 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.82:43325 fd=208 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.82:43326 fd=209 idle=1060095 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.82:43328 fd=211 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.80:53274 fd=213 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.80:53275 fd=214 idle=1060115 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.80:53276 fd=215 idle=1060227 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.80:53277 fd=216 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.80:53278 fd=217 idle=1061172 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.17:50308 fd=219 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.17:50310 fd=221 idle=1061194 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.80:53280 fd=232 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.80:53282 fd=234 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50162 fd=236 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.188.236:50163 fd=237 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.188.236:50164 fd=238 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.188.236:50165 fd=239 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.80:53284 fd=241 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.80:53285 fd=242 idle=1060114 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.80:53286 fd=243 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.80:53287 fd=244 idle=1061193 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.80:53288 fd=245 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.178.17:50312 fd=247 idle=1061192 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.17:50313 fd=248 idle=1060095 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.17:50314 fd=249 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=67.205.178.17:50315 fd=250 idle=1061192 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.17:50316 fd=251 idle=1061190 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.188.236:50167 fd=253 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50168 fd=255 idle=1060093 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=67.205.178.80:53291 fd=258 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.80:53292 fd=259 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.188.236:50170 fd=260 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.17:50319 fd=282 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.17:50320 fd=283 idle=1061191 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=67.205.178.68:34629 fd=290 idle=1061176 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=192.241.144.208:44052 fd=291 idle=1061176 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.178.68:34633 fd=292 idle=1060216 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=192.241.144.208:44057 fd=294 idle=1060875 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.160.130:35450 fd=588 idle=1051857 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.160.130:35452 fd=589 idle=1051349 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.137.222:33356 fd=590 idle=1051855 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.137.222:33363 fd=591 idle=1051359 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=67.205.137.222:57923 fd=602 idle=1051368 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=67.205.137.222:57925 fd=603 idle=1051349 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=196.52.43.62:6666 fd=665 idle=879946 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=5 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=NULL
addr=[workerIP1]:48367 fd=7 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP1]:48368 fd=8 idle=249155 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP1]:48369 fd=9 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP1]:48370 fd=10 idle=249155 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP1]:48371 fd=11 idle=13082 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP1]:48372 fd=12 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP1]:48373 fd=13 idle=249155 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP1]:48374 fd=14 idle=86 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP1]:48375 fd=15 idle=249155 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP1]:48376 fd=16 idle=1294 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP1]:48377 fd=17 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP1]:48378 fd=18 idle=249154 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP1]:48379 fd=19 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP1]:48380 fd=20 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP1]:48381 fd=21 idle=249154 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP1]:48382 fd=22 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP1]:48383 fd=27 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP1]:48384 fd=28 idle=249153 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP1]:48385 fd=29 idle=249153 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP1]:48386 fd=32 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP2]:45639 fd=34 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP2]:45640 fd=35 idle=249153 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP2]:45641 fd=39 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP2]:45642 fd=40 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP2]:45643 fd=41 idle=249153 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP2]:45644 fd=42 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP5]:56759 fd=43 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP5]:56760 fd=44 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56761 fd=45 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP5]:56762 fd=46 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56763 fd=47 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP3]:53711 fd=48 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP3]:53712 fd=49 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53713 fd=50 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP3]:53714 fd=52 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP3]:53715 fd=53 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53716 fd=54 idle=2846 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP5]:56764 fd=55 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP5]:56765 fd=56 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56766 fd=57 idle=86 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP5]:56767 fd=58 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56768 fd=59 idle=26 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP2]:45645 fd=60 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP2]:45646 fd=61 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP2]:45647 fd=62 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP2]:45648 fd=63 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60568 fd=64 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP4]:60569 fd=65 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP4]:60570 fd=66 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP4]:60571 fd=67 idle=249152 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP4]:60572 fd=68 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP5]:56769 fd=74 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP5]:56770 fd=75 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP5]:56771 fd=76 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP5]:56772 fd=77 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP5]:56773 fd=78 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP2]:45649 fd=79 idle=1 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP2]:45650 fd=80 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP2]:45651 fd=81 idle=85 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP2]:45652 fd=82 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP2]:45653 fd=83 idle=124354 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:40906 fd=84 idle=1 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:40907 fd=86 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:40908 fd=87 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40909 fd=109 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40910 fd=110 idle=53 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[masterIP]:40911 fd=116 idle=92 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[masterIP]:40912 fd=117 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40913 fd=123 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40914 fd=125 idle=20290 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:40915 fd=126 idle=1330 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP6]:57271 fd=127 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP3]:53717 fd=128 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP6]:57272 fd=129 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56774 fd=130 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP5]:56775 fd=131 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP5]:56776 fd=134 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP6]:57273 fd=135 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP3]:53718 fd=136 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP5]:56777 fd=137 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP5]:56778 fd=138 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP3]:53719 fd=142 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP6]:57274 fd=143 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53720 fd=146 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP6]:57275 fd=176 idle=37436 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP4]:60573 fd=190 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP4]:60574 fd=191 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP4]:60575 fd=192 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60576 fd=193 idle=249151 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60577 fd=194 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP2]:45654 fd=195 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP2]:45655 fd=196 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP2]:45656 fd=197 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP2]:45657 fd=207 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60578 fd=225 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP2]:45658 fd=226 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP4]:60579 fd=227 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP4]:60580 fd=228 idle=86 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[workerIP3]:53721 fd=229 idle=0 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[workerIP4]:60581 fd=230 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP4]:60582 fd=233 idle=16608 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP3]:53722 fd=240 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53723 fd=252 idle=86 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[masterIP]:40916 fd=254 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[masterIP]:40917 fd=256 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[masterIP]:40918 fd=257 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[masterIP]:40919 fd=261 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[masterIP]:40920 fd=262 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[masterIP]:40921 fd=267 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[masterIP]:40922 fd=268 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[masterIP]:40923 fd=281 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[masterIP]:40924 fd=284 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[masterIP]:40925 fd=288 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP3]:53724 fd=297 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53725 fd=298 idle=88 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP6]:57276 fd=299 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP6]:57277 fd=302 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP6]:57278 fd=303 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP6]:57279 fd=304 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP6]:57280 fd=305 idle=249150 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60583 fd=306 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP4]:60584 fd=326 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP4]:60585 fd=333 idle=249149 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60586 fd=335 idle=249149 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP4]:60587 fd=345 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP3]:53726 fd=364 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP3]:53727 fd=371 idle=249149 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[workerIP3]:53728 fd=373 idle=2 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=publish
addr=[workerIP3]:53729 fd=379 idle=1 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=1 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=psubscribe
addr=[workerIP3]:53730 fd=380 idle=249149 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=sadd
addr=[masterIP]:40926 fd=383 idle=249145 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40927 fd=384 idle=249145 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=exec
addr=[masterIP]:40932 fd=387 idle=249140 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40933 fd=391 idle=121 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:40934 fd=392 idle=84 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:40935 fd=393 idle=1892 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=unwatch
addr=[masterIP]:40936 fd=394 idle=249140 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40937 fd=395 idle=63 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:40938 fd=398 idle=249140 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:40940 fd=403 idle=135 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:40941 fd=406 idle=42 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:40942 fd=414 idle=51 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=unwatch
addr=[masterIP]:40946 fd=415 idle=90 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:40947 fd=416 idle=874 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=unwatch
addr=[workerIP5]:56796 fd=417 idle=249139 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56798 fd=418 idle=90846 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP4]:60601 fd=419 idle=249139 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP4]:60603 fd=420 idle=86 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP2]:45688 fd=421 idle=249138 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP2]:45690 fd=422 idle=26 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP3]:53755 fd=423 idle=249138 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP3]:53757 fd=424 idle=26 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:41011 fd=429 idle=249138 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[masterIP]:41012 fd=432 idle=2876 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[masterIP]:41013 fd=434 idle=2395 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=brpop
addr=[masterIP]:41014 fd=437 idle=2396 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=unwatch
addr=[workerIP5]:56880 fd=439 idle=249137 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
addr=[workerIP5]:56884 fd=441 idle=2844 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=lpush
addr=[workerIP2]:45725 fd=443 idle=249137 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 qbuf=0 obl=0 oll=0 events=r cmd=ping
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following:

- update `kombu>=3.0.33` https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/550
- `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'socket_timeout': 5}` https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2906
- change `timeout 0` to something higher in redis.conf (same source as for socket_timeout)
- after you catch "hang indefinitely" problem, look at `netstat -tpn |fgrep {redis port} |fgrep -c CLOSE_WAIT`, if there's a significant number, like > 5, this patch should help https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/pull/886
- say goodbye to Celery, it's not the last problem with it

I've had to setup celery worker restart cronjob at one site due to limitations of applying better options. Not listing above because it's an ugly crutch, not a solution.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am using `kombu>=3.0.33`. Per your suggestion, I've set `BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'socket_timeout': 5}` and changed the timeout in redis.conf to 20, but now within a couple minutes of running I'm getting these errors: `ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket: ('Connection closed by server.',)`. I continue getting this error even when setting `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT` to 0. How did you get around this issue after setting the timeouts?

Comment: @monstermac77 sorry, mate I don't have a solution, only another crutch `try/except ConnectionError: worker-quit`. It's a shame but acceptable with timeout of 10 minutes. I am very uncomfortable with these PHP-style fixes, business people don't care as long as it works.

Comment: Got it. I haven't tested this in production yet, but to handle my .get() hanging problem, I put `.get(timeout=x)` in a `try` and on `except` I execv (i.e. restart the execution of the script that's adding tasks). This appears to work since, interestingly, when my program hangs on `.get()`, restarting the workers _doesn't_ get tasks executing again, but restarting the script that's adding tasks to the queue/calling `.get()` _does_. Does knowing this reveal anything to you about the underlying issue? I agree, it's a terrible hack and makes me feel icky.

Comment: @monstermac77 Should've something to do with the way kombu emulates task queue features at client (adding script in this case). Study what Redis commands it executes on success and which doesn't get through when it hangs.